# Why do classes in the javax.sql package use new String(str)?

Tags: java

Many classes in the javax.sql package use `new String(str)` constructor. For example:

```
public void setCatalogName(int columnIndex, String catalogName) throws SQLException {
    checkColRange(columnIndex);
    if (catalogName != null)
        colInfo[columnIndex].catName = new String(catalogName);
    else
        colInfo[columnIndex].catName = new String("");
}
```

Or

```
public void setUsername(String name) {
    if(name == null)
    {
        username = null;
    } else {
        username = new String(name);
    }
}
```

And many more:

> javax.sql.rowset.serial.SerialStruct.SerialStruct(SQLData, Map>)
>   javax.sql.rowset.serial.SerialStruct.SerialStruct(Struct, Map>)
>   javax.sql.rowset.RowSetMetaDataImpl.setCatalogName(int, String)
>   javax.sql.rowset.RowSetMetaDataImpl.setColumnLabel(int, String)
>   javax.sql.rowset.RowSetMetaDataImpl.setColumnName(int, String)
>   javax.sql.rowset.RowSetMetaDataImpl.setColumnTypeName(int, String)
>   javax.sql.rowset.BaseRowSet.setCommand(String)
>   javax.sql.rowset.BaseRowSet.setDataSourceName(String)
>   java.text.DateFormatSymbols.setLocalPatternChars(String)
>   javax.sql.rowset.BaseRowSet.setNull(int, int, String)

What is the purpose of this? Isn't it creating unnecessary string instances on the heap?

Comment: According to which JDK implementation? OpenJDK?

Comment: JDK6, Oracle.... I just checked JDK7, and it is fixed there

Comment: Indeed, I'm not seeing any of it in [OpenJDK 7](http://grepcode.com/file_/repository.grepcode.com/java/root/jdk/openjdk/7-b147/javax/sql/rowset/RowSetMetaDataImpl.java).

Comment: Certainly `new String("")` is baffling.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It appears the code has been changed from JDK6 to JDK7 and all instances of `new String(str)` were removed. So, although Jon Skeet's suggestion is quite interesting, it was probably a lame piece of code they found and fixed.

Answer (score 9):

They're potentially protecting against the "small part of a big string" problem:

```
String x = getHugeStringFromSomewhere();
String y = x.substring(0, 5);
foo(y);
```

Now suppose the string referred to by `y` remains required, but `x` doesn't. Because `y` refers to the original `char[]`, you end up with that tiny string being responsible for a lot of memory.

If you create a new string instead, copying the data:

```
String x = getHugeStringFromSomewhere();
String y = new String(x.substring(0, 5));
foo(y);
```

... then the underlying large char array associated with the original string can be garbage collected at the same time as the string.

I've seen this make a huge difference when reading lots of tiny lines from a large text file (e.g. words in a dictionary). IIRC, `BufferedReader.readLine` creates a buffer of 80 characters, so each string returned pins at least an 80-character `char[]`, even if it's only 5 characters long. It all adds up... (As per comments, apparently this changed in Java 1.5 for `readLine` - but `substring` still works the same way.)

EDIT: Of course that's still only a guess as to the reason, and it definitely doesn't explain the `new String("")` part...

Comment: Thanks, substring working like that is something to consider.. The code in question is removed in JDK7 though, so probably it was just a lame piece of code they discovered and fixed :)

Comment: Even though this might not be the actual reason, it's still a great thing to note and consider about memory. +1

Comment: `new String("")`?? / The implementation of StringBuffer/String changed in 1.5 (eight years ago), now always copying the backing char[]. readLine only uses StringBuffer when a line crosses a buffer (default 8192 chars).

Comment: @TomHawtin-tackline: Ooh, interesting. It was well over 8 years ago that I had the problem :) But `substring` still has the same issue, right?

Comment: @JonSkeet Right at this moment, substring will do the same thing (major implementations). However, String is moving to a simpler/faster implementation without the offset and length. Ideally it would have the char[] integrated into to the same memory allocation. (Hidden away some Strings may actually use a byte[] instead of a char[] for compactness, and hence performance.)

Comment: @TomHawtin-tackline: Right - that sounds much more like the .NET implementation, other than the "sometimes using byte[]" (presumably for known-to-be-all-ASCII strings".

Comment: I've actually heard that `substring` is planned to change to the copying implementation in later Java 7 updates.